# Combining multiple csvs with different column names to unique column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to combine all csv files in a folder to a common csv files. The files have different column names but unique format (two columns in each files- one has code and the other has description). Need to develop a common csv files with all files with unique column names in a tidy way.

Folder is like below:

```
setwd("folder location")
file1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
file2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")
```

For reproducibility:

```
file1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                   A_code    A_desc 
                   n    15-24 
                   n    15-24
                   n    15-24
                   t    25-34 
                   p    35-44 
                   k    65-74
                   l    45-54
                   ")
file1
  A_code A_desc
1      n  15-24
2      n  15-24
3      n  15-24
4      t  25-34
5      p  35-44
6      k  35-44
7      l  45-54

file2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                   M_code    M_desc 
                   p    new 
                   p    new
                   p    new
                   a    old 
                   b    medium 
                   b    medium 
                   ")

file2
  M_code M_desc
1      p    new
2      p    new
3      p    new
4      a    old
5      b medium
6      b medium
```

The desirable output will be like below:

```
   Gen_code Gen_Desc Ori_code Ori_desc
1         n    15-24   A_code   A_desc
2         n    15-24   A_code   A_desc
3         n    15-24   A_code   A_desc
4         t    25-34   A_code   A_desc
5         p    35-44   A_code   A_desc
6         k    65-74   A_code   A_desc
7         l    45-54   A_code   A_desc
8         p      new   M_code   M_desc
9         p      new   M_code   M_desc
10        p      new   M_code   M_desc
11        a      old   M_code   M_desc
12        b   medium   M_code   M_desc
13        b   medium   M_code   M_desc
```

So far, I am able to do the following but it is not what I need.

```
path="folder location"
directory() %>%
  filter(endsWith(path, ".csv")) %>%
  select(path) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(path, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
library(tidyverse)

directory() %>%
  filter(endsWith(path, ".csv")) %>%
  pull(path) %>%
  map_df(~{
    .x %>%
      read_csv %>%
      mutate(Ori_code = names(.)[1], 
             Ori_desc = names(.)[2],
             across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
      rename_with(~c('Gen_code', 'Gen_Desc'), 1:2)
  }) -> result

result
```

Code inside `map_df` is what repeats for each file.

- Reads the csv
- Create two new columns `Ori_code` and `Ori_desc` which has the value from the two column names.
- Convert all the columns to character since if we have columns with mixed datatype we will not be able to merge them together in one dataset.
- Rename the 1st two columns to `c('Gen_code', 'Gen_Desc')`.
- Since we are using `map_df` it will combine all the files together into one `result`.